# Aircraft canopy Material

Tags: materials

so i was working on an aircraft [ tejas mk2 ] i faced a problem while making the canopy , iwant it to be exactly like this [image]
but i ended up like this [image]well i know it looks funny but yah i am an intermediate blender user ,what i wanted is a glass material that has such type of coulourish reflection as well as clear at the same time. soo.... please help me out , picture of the node settings would be much appreciated . cheers!
edit : here is my current progress [image]

Comment: Hello :). The effect is called iridescence. Luckily, it's pretty easy to fake it.

Comment: Jachym Michal yup thats what i wanted , let me try it

Comment: One more thing - to get good results, use HDRI lighting for your scene. Or your glass will always look flat (no reflections) :)

Comment: – Jachym Michal well thanks i got some okay kind of results a bit of more tweaking may help i guess , i have posted the image

Comment: Hey man, the result looks so cool! Is that a Rafale? And more importantly - where can I check more of your work? :)

Comment: Jachym Michal https://twitter.com/Raghuna86681990/status/1374404327175909379 , well its called tejas mk2 aka lca afmk2 from india , you can check out some of my works in my twitter handle . i just began moddeling these , so i havent yet posted anything much except for 4 more renders . thanks a lot mate